# Variable Declarations

Tags: java, variables, inheritance, types, declaration

```
Animal animal = new Animal();

Animal animal2 = new Dog();

Dog animal3 = new Dog();


public class Animal {

    int age;
    String name;

    public Animal() {
        name = "Empty";
        age = 0;
    }

    public Animal(int a, String n) {
        name = n;
        age = a;
    }

    public void move() {
        System.out.println("Moved");
    }
}

public class Dog extends Animal {

    public Dog() {
        this.name = "dog";
        this.age = 0;
    }

    public Dog(int a, String n){
        this.name = n;
        this.age = a;
    }
}
```

Hi, I'm learning `Java` and I would like to understand what are the differences between them. I know that `animal` is of type Animal and `animal3` is of type Dog but what is the type of `animal2`? What is actually going on here? Thank you.

Comment: Learn about inheritance

Comment: And about polymorphism. That's one of examples of using this property of OOP.

Comment: This  concept is known as Upcasting in java, because we are casting it to a supertype here Animal, animal2 is still a dog object referencing Animal. It is totally valid because if  you see Dog is a Animal. (Beware while downcasting as it throws `ClassCastException`)

Comment: What you're missing is this - a variable has a _type_ but an object has a _class_ (although classes are actually types).  The _type_ of a reference variable doesn't have to be the same as the _class_ of the object that it refers to.  In this case, the _type_ of _two_ of your reference variables matches the class of the corresponding _object_, but there is one reference variable that refers to an object whose _class_ is different from the _type_ of the variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Animal animal2 = new Dog();
```

`Dog` class is subclass of `Animal` because class `Dog` inherit properties of class `Animal`,Because of this reference of Class Animal holds object of its sub-classes that is class Dog But if you want call method that's is `override` in class Dog . method of class `Dog` will be called .

Answer of your question :

Object  `animal2` is type class Dog. but its reference variable of class `Animal`.

Comment: If animal2 is type class Dog, and its reference variable is of class Animal, when I invoke a method of the same name, does it use methods from class Animal or class Dog?

Comment: method of class Dog will be called .

Answer (score 0):

Animal animal2 = new Dog();
This Comes under over riding Concept.Over Riding is a polymorphism Concept where The Method of parent class is used by the child class.

Answer (score 0):

```
   Animal animal = new Animal();

   Animal animal2 = new Dog();

   Dog animal3 = new Dog();
```

This three line are your declaration of three objects `anima animal2 animal3`

From you main class Animal you have two different constructor

first is `public Animal()` where it doesn't have any parameter and the second one is `public Animal(int a, String n)`

After that you have a subclass `Dog` where it inherited the properties of your main class `Animal`

inside you subclass `Dog` has two constructor also `public Dog` and `public Dog(int a, String n)`

From the declaration of your object above you call what constructor you will use.

Better read the java documentation for further learning [click here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/)